Show that $f:(0,2) \to S^1$ defined by $f(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$ is not a covering map.
I want to show that $f(x) = e^{2\pi ix}$ as a map from $(0,2) \subset \mathbb{R}$ to $S^1$ is not a covering map. What I have realized so far, I think, is that since the sheets of the covering needs to be open intervals  (since the only open connected subsets of $(0,2)$ are open intervals $(a_i,b_i)$), we need to find a neighborhood $U \subseteq S^1$ with $1 \in U$ such that $$f^{-1}(U) = \coprod\limits_{i \in I} (a_i,b_i)$$ and such that for each $i$, we have that $f|_{(a_i,b_i)}:(a_i,b_i) \to U$ is a homeomorphism. Now, since $1 \in S^1$, and $f|_{(a_i,b_i)}$ agrees with $f$ on $(a_i,b_i)$, there can only be one such interval $(a_i,b_i)$ that contains $1$ such that its image is homeomorphic to $U$. This in itself I don't see as a contradiction (unless I have misunderstood what it means to have multiple sheets; must there really be more than one?). How do I proceed to show that this leads to a contradiction (or show what I want to show directly)?

How many preimages do the points of $U$ have?

oh, are you are talking about the fact that the cardinality of the fiber $f^{-1}(x)$ for $x \in U$ needs to be the same for all elements $x \in U$?

Yes, he certainly is

Well, ok, all other points satisfy $f(x) = f(x+1)$, unless I am mistaken, so they should have cardinality $|f^{-1}(x)| = 2$, for $x \neq 1$. Hmm.

Right, that is enough then, unless I am being too optimistic, since any $U$ will contain other points besides $x = 1$, but $f(x) = f(x+1)$ for $x \in (0,2) \setminus{1}$ shows that it can not be evenly covered.

You don't even have to refer to "evenly covered". You can just count the number of preimages, and exhibit two points in the base space that don't have the same number.

Right, you mean I don't even have to think about evenly covered sets $U \subseteq X$, I can just take any two points $x,y$ where $x \neq y$ and one of them is $1$? If yes, then I agree. Thanks for the input! =)

You are right that there don't have to be multiple sheets - every space is trivially a 1-fold cover of itself, via the identity map.
As for what you want to prove: you probably either already know, or else it's not too hard to prove, that a path between points in the base can, via liftings, create a bijection between the set of preimages of the starting point and the set of preimages of the ending point. So, as the commenter suggests, you can probably just get away with counting the number of preimages various points have.

Well, it looks like the OP picked up exactly what the first comment was pointing to, but I think I'll leave this answer, as it fleshes out a few more of the details.
